# Does Hartree-Fock method always converge to global energy minimum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, variational-principle, orbitals

I'm not asking about whether the Hartree-Fock method will always converge, but, if it does, it seems like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics)) is saying that it will always converge to the global minimum energy of the TISE.

> Minimising the expected energy is, in general, is not an easy task, since we are looking for a global minimum and finding the zeroes of the partial derivatives of $\varepsilon$ over all $\alpha+i$ is not sufficient. If $\psi(\alpha)$ is expressed as a linear combination of other functions ($\alpha_i$ being the coefficients), as in the Ritz method, there is only one minimum and the problem is straightforward. There are other, non-linear methods, however, such as the Hartree–Fock method, that are also not characterized by a multitude of minima and are therefore comfortable in calculations.

Is this true and if so, how?